# XSLT 2.0: filter duplicates

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have this line in a template:

`<xsl:for-each select="//img/@src[not(@ = preceding::@)]">`

to generate a list of filenames of pictures :

`<img src="mypic1.jpg"/>`

Now I need to filter duplicate pictures from the list of pictures.

`<xsl:for-each select="//img[not(node() = preceding::img)]">`

does not work because it works on the whole image node.
How can I change the line to work on src attributes?
So the question is about the last part of the line in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `distinct-values(//img/@src)`, e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//img/@src)">
  <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
<xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively you can use for-each-group

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//img" group-by="@src">
  <li><xsl:value-of select="@src"/></li>
<xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. and insde that loop, hou would I use generate-id() on the parent node img? (in your first suggestion)

Comment: @Erik you can't, because `distinct-values` gives you the distinct _values_, not the nodes they came from (i.e. you're for-eaching over a sequence of atomic values, not a sequence of nodes).

Comment: I see. Of course. Then I'll use position() and a prefix to generate id's. Thanks again.

Comment: @Erik with the `for-each-group` version you _can_ use `generate-id()` because in that case `.` is the first `img` element in document order that has the current `@src` value (and `current-group()` will give you all the members of the group if you need them).